# loopback model with object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, loopbackjs

Good evening,

I just started with loopback (literally), so I went for the commands explained in the documentation:

Started the loopback project with the command:

```
slc loopback
```

Generated a model with the loopback model generator with the command:

```
slc loopback:model
```

When the generator starts, it asks for model name, storing method, base class, plural, whether we want it to be a common model or a server model. After that it asks for the properties of the model.

I have a model that could be like this:

```
MODEL NAME
Property1 : String,
Property2 : String,
Property3 : Number,
Property4 : {
            obj.Property1 : String,
            obj.Property2 : String,
            obj.Property3 : String
            },
Property5 : String
```

I thought that by choosing "Object" as the type of property it would ask me for additional properties on that object, but it didn't. Now I have no idea how to create those additional properties that are inside the object of this model.

How would I go about creating the properties that are nested inside the `Property4 Object`? Am I missing something from the `loopback:model` generator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `slc loopback:model` doesn't do that. You just have to specify yourself in the generated json file(possibly in common/models/ directory) in the `properties` object:

```
"properties": {
  ...
  "Property4": {
    "type": {
      "Property1" : "String",
      "Property2" : "String",
      "Property3" : "String"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

If you want any of the properties to be required you can do it like this:

```
"properties": {
  ...
  "Property4": {
    "type": {
      "Property1" : {
        "type": "String"
        "required": true
      },
      "Property2" : "String",
      "Property3" : "String"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

If the object doesn't have a "type" property, you can just do this:

```
"properties": {
  ...
  "Property4": {
    "Property1" : "String",
    "Property2" : "String",
    "Property3" : "String"
  },
  ...
}
```

You can also put this definition into a another model and reference that here:

```
"properties": {
  ...
  "Property4": "AnotherModel",
  ...
}
```

I suggest you read through the ['properties' section of this document](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#properties) and also ['object types' section of this document](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/LoopBack-types.html#object-types).