# Swagger in Loopback 4 - using @property decorator to represent nested objects

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, loopback, openapi, loopback4

**TL;DR**
How do I create a Model that includes nested Objects without creating a new Model for every property that is of type Object?

New to LB4 & Typescript so apologies if this is an obv question. I want to create a Model which represents a Response that includes a nested Object for my endpoint. Here is a sample response:

```
{
  "result": {
    "prop1": "blah blah",
    "prop2": {
      "subProp": {
        "subSubProp": "blah blah"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Problem I have is representing the nested object inside of my Model. Ideally I would do something like this:

```js
@model()
export class MyResponseModel extends Model {
  @property({
    type: 'object'
  })
  result: {
    prop1: string,
    prop2: {
      subProp: {
        subSubProp: string
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my controller I would set this as the response type:

```js
@post('/my-endpoint', {
  responses: {
    ...,
    schema: {
      'x-ts-type': MyResponseModel,
    }
  }
})
async post(): Promise<MyResponseModel>{...}
```

The only way I have got this working so far is creating a Model for every nested object i.e. a Model for "result", another for "prop2" and another for "subProp" which doesn't feel is the right way to implement this? In LB3 it looks like you can specify a "properties" prop to define child objects which can also have sub objects.

Same q asked for LB3 but doesn't answer it for LB4: [loopback model with object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137597/loopback-model-with-object)

Asked in google group with no answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/loopbackjs/AKgZT6V-pCc

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I create a Model that includes nested Objects without creating a new Model for every property that is of type Object?
>
> Same q asked for LB3 but doesn't answer it for LB4: [loopback model with object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137597/loopback-model-with-object)

The solution described in the answer to your LB3 question should work in LoopBack 4.

```
@model()
export class MyResponseModel extends Model {
  @property({
    type: {
      prop1: 'string',
      prop2: {
        type: {
          subSubProp: 'string'
        }
      }
    }
  })
  result: {
    prop1: string,
    prop2: {
      subProp: {
        subSubProp: string
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A short-hand notation should work too:

```
@model()
export class MyResponseModel extends Model {
  @property({
    prop1: 'string',
    prop2: {
      subSubProp: 'string'
    }
  })
  result: {
    prop1: string,
    prop2: {
      subProp: {
        subSubProp: string
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Functionally it does work but the swagger explorer doesn't show the sub props i.e. you will just see example response as `result: {}` and that's it

Comment: @ahb I guess that means the code building JSON/OpenAPI Schema from LB4 model definitions does not support nested models yet. Can you open a new feature request please? https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/new?labels=feature&template=Feature_request.md